# Error in eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : 0 x 0 matrix in MetRology uncertMC with 2x2 correlation matrix

Tags: r, montecarlo

I am attempting to learn how to use the MetRology package in R. I have been using the data in Appendix H.2 of the GUM manual as a simple example to attempt Monte Carlo  uncertainty propagation including correlation. I have two variables V and I. Therefore I have a 2x2 correlation matrix with the correlation between I,V  in the off-diagonal elements. If I supply this matrix to the uncertMC function, I get the error: "Error in eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : 0 x 0 matrix". If I do not include the correlation matrix, I do not get the error. Why am I getting the error when correlation is included? The metRology manual  has  an example  with four variables and a 4x4 correlation matrix which works for me. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

```
library(errors) # for gum H.2 dataset
library(metRology) # for uncertMC

#extract relevant data

meanV  <-  with(GUM.H.2, mean(V))
meanI  <-  with(GUM.H.2, mean(I))

#uncertainties of the mean as per GUM (over sqrt(N))

uV <-  with(GUM.H.2, sd(V)/sqrt(length(V)))
uI <-  with(GUM.H.2, sd(I)/sqrt(length(I)))

# correlation between V and I

corIV  <-  with(GUM.H.2, cor(I,V))

#set up a 2 x 2 correlation matrix

u.cor <-  diag(1,2)

# off-diagonal elements

u.cor[1,2] <- u.cor[2,1] <-  corIV

#set up inputs for uncertMC

# the expression Z = V/I

expr <-  expression(V/I)

x <- list(V= meanV, I= meanI)

u  <-  list(V=uV, I=uI)

u.MC <-  uncertMC(expr = expr, x = x, u = u, cor = u.cor)

#errors with Error in eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : 0 x 0 matrix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking traceback & uncertMC function and there is a piece of code to define Sigma:

```
Sigma = cov[cor.vars, cor.vars]
```

but `cor.vars` is defined as:

```
cor.vars <- which(rowSums(cor) > (1 + .Machine$double.eps * 
            nrow(cor)))
```

the issue is that if you have negative correlations, eventually `rowSums(cor)` will not meet the condition, so you will get `integer(0)`.

As you said, the metRology manual has an example with four variables and a 4x4 correlation matrix which works for you, but if you change the sign of correlation you get the same error:

```
expr <- expression(a+b*2+c*3+d/2)
x <- list(a=1, b=3, c=2, d=11)
u <- lapply(x, function(x) x/10)
u.cor<-diag(1,4)
u.cor[3,4]<-u.cor[4,3]<- -0.5 # change sign to negative
u.formc.MC<-uncertMC(~a+b*2+c*3+d/2, x, u, cor=u.cor, keep.x=TRUE)
u.formc.MC

# Error in eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : 0 x 0 matrix
```